# Browser cannot connect to Processing Server

Tags: networking, browser, server, processing

I am running the example sketches for a server and client:

Client:

```
/**
 * Shared Drawing Canvas (Client) 
 * by Alexander R. Galloway. 
 * 
 * The Processing Client class is instantiated by specifying a remote 
 * address and port number to which the socket connection should be made. 
 * Once the connection is made, the client may read (or write) data to the server.
 * Before running this program, start the Shared Drawing Canvas (Server) program.
 */


import processing.net.*;

Client c;
String input;
int data[];

void setup() 
{
  size(450, 255);
  background(204);
  stroke(0);
  frameRate(5); // Slow it down a little
  // Connect to the server's IP address and port
  c = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 8080); // Replace with your server's IP and port
}

void draw() 
{
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    // Draw our line
    stroke(255);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
    // Send mouse coords to other person
    c.write(pmouseX + " " + pmouseY + " " + mouseX + " " + mouseY + "\n");
  }
  // Receive data from server
  if (c.available() > 0) {
    input = c.readString();
    input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("\n")); // Only up to the newline
    data = int(split(input, ' ')); // Split values into an array
    // Draw line using received coords
    stroke(0);
    line(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
  }
}
```

Server:

```
/**
 * Shared Drawing Canvas (Server) 
 * by Alexander R. Galloway. 
 * 
 * A server that shares a drawing canvas between two computers. 
 * In order to open a socket connection, a server must select a 
 * port on which to listen for incoming clients and through which 
 * to communicate. Once the socket is established, a client may 
 * connect to the server and send or receive commands and data.
 * Get this program running and then start the Shared Drawing
 * Canvas (Client) program so see how they interact.
 */


import processing.net.*;

Server s;
Client c;
String input;
int data[];

void setup() 
{
  size(450, 255);
  background(204);
  stroke(0);
  frameRate(5); // Slow it down a little
  s = new Server(this, 8080); // Start a simple server on a port
}

void draw() 
{
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    // Draw our line
    stroke(255);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
    // Send mouse coords to other person
    s.write(pmouseX + " " + pmouseY + " " + mouseX + " " + mouseY + "\n");
  }
  // Receive data from client
  c = s.available();
  if (c != null) {
    input = c.readString();
    input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("\n")); // Only up to the newline
    data = int(split(input, ' ')); // Split values into an array
    // Draw line using received coords
    stroke(0);
    line(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
  }
}
```

Now I think I should be able to inspect what the server is doing when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8080/. Unfortunately my browser seems to be unable to establish a connection with the server. Have I done something wrong and can it be fixed or are my expectations unrealistic?

Answer (score 0):

The server and the client communicate via a [network socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). They pass data in a format that is not understandable for your browser. The way to get the example to run is to launch the server first and the client second (you need to start the Processing environment two times). Now you should be able to draw lines on one side and see them being copied on the other side.

If you want to inspect what the server and client are doing, you can add println statements to the code.

The example code that you are using can be found here on GitHub:
https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/java/libraries/net/examples